# Calling a model outside the traditional models within the penalized package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I am attempting to run a penalized regression on claims data, where the penalized covariates are simply the origin and development year and there are no unpenalized covariates. There are occasions where you run across negative 'y values' which is a nightmare as the link function is log.

A work around this is defining the 'quasipoisson', I believe David Firth wrote the following code:

```
quasipoisson <- function (link = "log")
      ## Amended by David Firth, 2003.01.16, at points labelled ###
      ## to cope with negative y values
      ##
      ## Computes Pearson X^2 rather than Poisson deviance
      ##
      ## Starting values are all equal to the global mean
    {
      linktemp <- substitute(link)
      if (!is.character(linktemp)) {
        linktemp <- deparse(linktemp)
        if (linktemp == "link")
          linktemp <- eval(link)
      }
      if (any(linktemp == c("log", "identity", "sqrt")))
        stats <- make.link(linktemp)
      else stop(paste(linktemp, "link not available for
                      poisson",
                      "family; available links are", "\"identity\", \"log\"
                      and \"sqrt\""))
      variance <- function(mu) mu
      validmu <- function(mu) all(mu > 0)
      dev.resids <- function(y, mu, wt) wt*(y-mu)^2/mu ###
      aic <- function(y, n, mu, wt, dev) NA
      initialize <- expression({
        n <- rep(1, nobs)
        mustart <- rep(mean(y), length(y)) ###
      })
  structure(list(family = "quasipoisson", link = linktemp,
                 linkfun = stats$linkfun, linkinv = stats$linkinv,
                 variance = variance,
                 dev.resids = dev.resids, aic = aic, mu.eta =
                   stats$mu.eta,
                 initialize = initialize, validmu = validmu, valideta =
                   stats$valideta),
            class = "family")
}
```

This acts as a workaround, as is great when applying a standard GLM to claims data, ie you have:

```
model <- glm(claims ~ origin + dev, family = quasipoisson(),
             subset=!is.na(claims), data=dataset)
```

Now I am interested to apply penalized regression in a similar manner, as issues will arise with log link I would like to introduce this new family. I am very new to this area, but I have imported the package 'penalized' in R, and have tried the following:

```
GLM_train<-penalized(claims,~origin+dev,unpenalized=~0,data=df_train,model="quasipoisson", lambda2=1)
```

Where `'df_train'` is simply a dataframe containing three columns:

`'claims'` - the aggregate claim amount (wrt the triangle)

`'origin'`- the claim origin

`'dev'` - the development period (in months)

An example of df_train:

```
claims<-c(0.000,  8752.912, 16357.009, 20878.468, 22479.931, 21516.718, 22413.001, 22488.901, 21516.718, 23285.851 ,21793.339, 22765.522,
12253.054, 14257.608 ,19807.112 ,21696.767 ,22040.339, 21004.614 ,22061.039 ,22061.039, 20678.934, 21735.359, 20678.934, 21735.359)

origin<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

dev <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
df_test=data.frame(claims=claims,origin=origin,dev=dev)
```

I have tried playing around with the models that are within the package, but the GLM does not converge. I am hoping that the introduction of the quasipoisson will alter this, is there anyway to run the penalized regression with the model as this predefinined quasipoisson?

Apologies again if trivial - I am very new to this!

Thanks!

Comment: @Hack-R In a nutshell! Yes exactly

Comment: I have added reproducible code in hope to make my question clearer! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've added an upvote now that it is reproducible. I'll try to take a crack at it during lunch if I have time.

Comment: Thanks Hack-R, just to say upon manipulation of the data I realise that the error is partially due to the data. After amending and making it similar to the reproducible data the concern is still the same. I need a family outside the traditional models in the package (namely the quasipoisson, that I've defined). Thanks!